# how to use sdl gui (SDL_SetVideoMode,....) in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-platform, video-streaming, sdl

I am planning to use the SDL library in order to render some video streaming in the android screen .
For that i started by cross compiling the sdl library for the android ICS version.

Then i created a small jni file where i only put this 2 instructions in my method:

```
 SDL_Surface *screen;
 LOGI("screen");
 screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320, 240, 0, 0);
```

But no matter values i put in the  SDL_SetVideoMode(,,,) i always get a segmentation fault (segv 11 code=1).

I wonder is this the right way to render sdl gui in the android screen?

I am really stuck now and i dont know how to bypass this error!!

I would be thankfull if someone could help me!!!